# Intersection of two local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, local-rings

I have been thinking about this question alot but couldn't figure out an answer.

> Is intersection of two local rings again a local ring?

I can't find any counterexample. So any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The intersection of two arbitrary rings is not even a ring - you need some condition to ensure that at first

Comment: I am sorry but obviously I am assuming intersection is not empty and they are forming a ring.

Comment: A concrete counterexample: $\mathbb Z_{(2)}\cap\mathbb Z_{(3)}$.

Comment: Thanks for the concrete counter example. Correct me if I am wrong  $\mathbb Z_{(2)}\cap\mathbb Z_{(3)}$ isn't local because   $3\mathbb Z_{(2)} / \mathbb Z_{(2)}\cap\mathbb Z_{(3)}$ and  $2\mathbb Z_{(2)} / \mathbb Z_{(2)}\cap\mathbb Z_{(3)}$ are two maximal ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intersection of two Local rings should not necessarily be local again. One can show that every integral domain $R$ is given as the  intersection $\bigcap R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ of all its localizations at maximal ideals (considered as subrings of the field of fraction). By that you can at least see that this does not hold for general intersections. To get your example for two local rings, we can try to  find an integral domain with exactly 2 maximal ideals. Choose two valuation rings of a field $K$ not containing each other and consider their intersection. This yields an integral domain with two maximal ideals (or more generally one with $n$ maximal ideals). The latter result can be found in the book multiplicative ideal theory by Gilmer (Theorem 22.8).

Comment: To find an integral domain with exactly two maximal ideals, can't you localize an integral domain at every maximal ideal except for two of them ? Like take $m_1,m_2$ maximal (or prime actually)  and distinct and invert $R\setminus (m_1\cup m_2)$ which is multiplicative as the intersection of two multiplicative sets.

Comment: Yes, that should work as well. This uses more geometric intuition as you are pretty much just removing all closed points from the spectrum except for 2.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another follow-up question I have in mind, can we put any condition on the local rings to make there intersection local